# Custom css radiobuttons hover effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, label

i'm trying to create something like [this](http://www.apple.com/shop/buy-iphone/iphone6s)
but i'm not that good with javascript and so..
So i got this now, but i can't get the hover effect to work..

```
 <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="all" checked>
   <label for="radio1">iPhone</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="false">
   <label for="radio2">Galaxy S IV</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="true">
   <label for="radio3">Nexus S</label>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And CSS

```
input[type=radio] {
  display:none;
  margin:10px;
}

input[type=radio] + label {
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 18px 112px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background-image: none;
  border: 2px solid #08c;
}
```

Well this works but how do i make a hover effect? Any help would be usefull! Also if you think i should do this completely different please tell me

Answer (score 3):

Just do it with plain CSS.

```css
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px;
}
input[type=radio] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 18px 112px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
input[type=radio] + label:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background-image: none;
  border: 2px solid #08c;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="all" checked>
<label for="radio1">iPhone</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="false">
<label for="radio2">Galaxy S IV</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="true">
<label for="radio3">Nexus S</label>
```

You could even go more fancy and add some transitions (most browsers support them nowdays http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)

```css
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px;
}
input[type=radio] + label {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 18px 112px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
input[type=radio] + label:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: LightGray;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background-image: none;
  border: 2px solid #08c;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="all" checked>
<label for="radio1">iPhone</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="false">
<label for="radio2">Galaxy S IV</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="true">
<label for="radio3">Nexus S</label>
```